# jQuery set var where n is ID for tabindex order?

Tags: jquery

How to combine the two scripts below, into one, with the goal to get a script to generate a tabindex order feature for input/select fields in a form (where 1, 7, 3 are ID (#) of fields)?

```
$(function(){
var tabindex = 1;
$('input,select').each(function() {
    if (this.type != "hidden") {
        var $input = $(this);
        $input.attr("tabindex", tabindex);
        tabindex++;
    }
});
});


$(function () {
var tab_order_positions = [1, 7, 3],
tab_order = 0;
for (var i = 0, _len = tab_order_positions.length; i < _len; i++) {
    $('#input_' + tab_order_positions[i]).attr('tabindex', ++tab_order);
}
});
```

Comment: "how to modify it" is a very generic question, what is your requirement and what did you want to do ?

Comment: Can't help you if you don't ask an appropriately specific question.

Comment: Doesn't the second script already do what you asking for?

Comment: Ilia G: In a way yes but when I hit tab the cursor moves out of the form. It looses focus so to say.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var tab_order_positions = ['1', '7', '3']
            var tabindex = tab_order_positions.length;

            $.each(tab_order_positions, function (i, tab_order_position) {
                $('#input_' + tab_order_position).attr('tabindex', i);
            });

            $('input, select').each(function (i) {
                var obj = $(this);

                if (obj.attr('type') != 'hidden' && (obj.attr('id') !== undefined && $.inArray(obj.attr('id').split('_')[1], tab_order_positions)) === false) {
                    obj.attr('tabindex', tabindex);
                    tabindex++;
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    Name:<input type="text" id="input_1" /><br />
    <input type="hidden" /><br />
    <input type="hidden" /><br />
    Age:
    <input type="text" id="input_3" /><br />
    Birth:
    <input type="text" /><br />
    Test:<select>
        <option>a</option>
        <option>b</option>
    </select><br />
    Gender:
    <input type="radio" name="gender" />
    Male
    <input type="radio" name="gender" />Female
    <br />
    Vechical:
    <input type="checkbox" name="Vechical" /><br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="Vechical" /><br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="Vechical" /><br />
    <input type="hidden" />
    test1:
    <input type="text" id="input_7" /><br />
    test2:
    <input type="text" /><br />
    test3:
    <input type="text" /><br />
    test4:
    <input type="text" /><br />
</body>
</html>
```